# libVLC Error: cannot create muxer

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I am trying to stream with vlc usign this command:

```
-vvv Foreman_H264.mp4 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}: rtp{mux=ts,dst=239.255.12.42,sdp=sap,name="TestStream"}'
```

this command works fine with a standard installation of vlc.
But now i have installed a short version of vlc with only this librarys:

- ncurses
- xcb
- a52
- ffmpeg
- libxml
- alsa
- live

When i run the same command i get this error messages:

```
[00007f0194001318] stream_out_rtp stream out error: cannot create muxer
```

and

```
[00007f0194000c18] core stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}: rtp{mux=ts,dst=239.255.12.42,sdp=sap,name="TestStream"}'
[00007f01a00009b8] core input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
```

It seems like I am still missing a library. But I don't know which one ? I thought the live library would do the job for rtp streaming.

Here the full log:

```
    -vvv Foreman_H264.mp4 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}: rtp{mux=ts,dst=239.255.12.42,sdp=sap,name="TestStream"}'
VLC media player 2.2.0 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.0-0-g1349ef2)
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.2.0 Weatherwax
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2015 the VideoLAN team
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: revision 2.2.0-0-g1349ef2
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: configured with ./configure  '--disable-mad' '--disable-libgcrypt' '--disable-lua'
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/local/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/local/lib/vlc/plugins'
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: saving plugins cache /usr/local/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 326 modules
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: opening config file (/home/stud/.config/vlc/vlcrc)
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 FPU 
[0000000000fd8988] core input debug: Creating an input for 'Media Library'
[0000000000fd8988] core input debug: Input is a meta file: disabling unneeded options
[0000000000fd8988] core input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
[0000000000fd8988] core input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/stud/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' gives access `file' demux `xspf-open' path `/home/stud/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0000000000fd8988] core input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/stud/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/stud/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0000000000fde228] core demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 11 candidates
[0000000000fde228] core demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[0000000000fd8988] core input debug: creating access 'file' location='/home/stud/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf', path='/home/stud/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0000000000fde228] core access debug: looking for access module matching "file": 17 candidates
[0000000000fde228] filesystem access debug: opening file `/home/stud/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0000000000fde228] core access debug: using access module "filesystem"
[0000000000fbe048] core stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[0000000000fbe048] core stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[0000000000fbe048] core stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[0000000000fbe048] core stream debug: pre-buffering done 296 bytes in 0s - 4379 KiB/s
[0000000000fbe2a8] core stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 7 candidates
[0000000000fbe2a8] core stream debug: no stream_filter modules matched
[0000000000fbe2a8] core stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 7 candidates
[0000000000fbe2a8] core stream debug: using stream_filter module "record"
[0000000000fd8988] core input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/stud/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/stud/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0000000000fc2078] core demux debug: looking for demux module matching "xspf-open": 56 candidates
[0000000000fc2078] xspf demux debug: using XSPF playlist reader
[0000000000fc2078] core demux debug: using demux module "playlist"
[0000000000fc22e8] core demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 0 candidates
[0000000000fc22e8] core demux meta debug: no meta reader modules
[0000000000fd8988] core input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/stud/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' successfully opened
[0000000000fc2208] core xml reader debug: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
[0000000000fc2208] core xml reader debug: using xml reader module "xml"
[0000000000fc2078] xspf demux debug: parsed 0 tracks successfully
[0000000000fd8988] core input debug: EOF reached
[0000000000fc2078] core demux debug: removing module "playlist"
[0000000000fbe2a8] core stream debug: removing module "record"
[0000000000fde228] core access debug: removing module "filesystem"
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: creating audio output
[0000000000fbe048] core audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "any": 4 candidates
[0000000000fbe048] alsa audio output debug: Available ALSA PCM devices:
[0000000000fbe048] alsa audio output debug: Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture) (null)
[0000000000fbe048] alsa audio output debug: Intel 82801AA-ICH, Intel 82801AA-ICH Default Audio Device (default:CARD=I82801AAICH)
[0000000000fbe048] alsa audio output debug: Intel 82801AA-ICH, Intel 82801AA-ICH Default Audio Device (sysdefault:CARD=I82801AAICH)
[0000000000fbe048] alsa audio output debug: Intel 82801AA-ICH, Intel 82801AA-ICH Front speakers (front:CARD=I82801AAICH,DEV=0)
[0000000000fbe048] alsa audio output debug: Intel 82801AA-ICH, Intel 82801AA-ICH 2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers (surround21:CARD=I82801AAICH,DEV=0)
[0000000000fbe048] alsa audio output debug: Intel 82801AA-ICH, Intel 82801AA-ICH 4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers (surround40:CARD=I82801AAICH,DEV=0)
[0000000000fbe048] alsa audio output debug: Intel 82801AA-ICH, Intel 82801AA-ICH 4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers (surround41:CARD=I82801AAICH,DEV=0)
[0000000000fbe048] alsa audio output debug: Intel 82801AA-ICH, Intel 82801AA-ICH 5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers (surround50:CARD=I82801AAICH,DEV=0)
[0000000000fbe048] alsa audio output debug: Intel 82801AA-ICH, Intel 82801AA-ICH 5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers (surround51:CARD=I82801AAICH,DEV=0)
[0000000000fbe048] alsa audio output debug: Intel 82801AA-ICH, Intel 82801AA-ICH IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output (iec958:CARD=I82801AAICH,DEV=0)
[0000000000fbe048] core audio output debug: using audio output module "alsa"
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: keeping audio output
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: adding item `Foreman_H264.mp4' ( file:///home/stud/Big_One/LB-KA_01/Foreman_H264.mp4 )
[000000000102ddf8] core interface debug: looking for interface module matching "hotkeys,none": 9 candidates
[00007f01a4000958] core input debug: Creating an input for 'Foreman_H264.mp4'
[000000000102ddf8] core interface debug: using interface module "hotkeys"
[0000000000fd8988] core interface debug: looking for interface module matching "globalhotkeys,none": 9 candidates
[0000000000fd8988] core interface debug: using interface module "xcb_hotkeys"
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0000000000fdf6e8] core interface debug: looking for interface module matching "any": 9 candidates
Remote control interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
[0000000000fdf6e8] core interface debug: using interface module "oldrc"
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: processing request item: null, node: Playlist, skip: 0
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index -1
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: resyncing on Foreman_H264.mp4
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: Foreman_H264.mp4 is at 0
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: creating new input thread
[00007f01a00009b8] core input debug: Creating an input for 'Foreman_H264.mp4'
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: requesting art for Foreman_H264.mp4
[00007f0194000c18] core stream output debug: using sout chain=`transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}: rtp{mux=ts,dst=239.255.12.42,sdp=sap,name="TestStream"}'
[00007f0198000958] core art finder debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 0 candidates
[00007f0198000958] core art finder debug: no meta fetcher modules
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: searching art for Foreman_H264.mp4
[00007f0198000958] core art finder debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 1 candidates
[00007f0194000c18] core stream output debug: stream=`rtp'
[00007f0194001318] core stream out debug: looking for sout stream module matching "rtp": 20 candidates
[00007f0198000958] core art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[00007f0198000958] core art finder debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 0 candidates
[00007f0198000958] core art finder debug: no meta fetcher modules
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: searching art for Foreman_H264.mp4
[00007f0198000958] core art finder debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 1 candidates
[00007f0198000958] core art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: art not found for Foreman_H264.mp4
[00007f0194001318] core stream out debug: set config option: sout-rtp-mux to ts
[00007f0194001318] core stream out debug: set config option: sout-rtp-dst to 239.255.12.42
[00007f0194001318] core stream out debug: set config option: sout-rtp-sdp to sap
[00007f0194001318] core stream out debug: set config option: sout-rtp-name to TestStream
[00007f0194003bf8] core mux debug: looking for sout mux module matching "ts": 8 candidates
[00007f0194003bf8] core mux debug: no sout mux modules matched
[00007f0194001318] stream_out_rtp stream out error: cannot create muxer
[00007f0194001318] core stream out debug: no sout stream modules matched
[00007f0194001318] core stream out debug: destroying chain... (name=(null))
[00007f0194001318] core stream out debug: destroying chain done
[00007f0194000c18] core stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}: rtp{mux=ts,dst=239.255.12.42,sdp=sap,name="TestStream"}'
[00007f01a00009b8] core input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: finished input
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: dead input
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: nothing to play
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: meta ok for (null), need to fetch art
[00007f01a4001ce8] core art finder debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 0 candidates
[00007f01a4001ce8] core art finder debug: no meta fetcher modules
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: searching art for Foreman_H264.mp4
[00007f01a4003da8] core art finder debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 1 candidates
[00007f01a4003da8] core art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[00007f01a4003628] core art finder debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 0 candidates
[00007f01a4003628] core art finder debug: no meta fetcher modules
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: searching art for Foreman_H264.mp4
[00007f01a40017a8] core art finder debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 1 candidates
[00007f01a40017a8] core art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: art not found for Foreman_H264.mp4
^C[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: removing all interfaces
[0000000000f23118] core libvlc debug: exiting
[0000000000fdf6e8] core interface debug: removing module "oldrc"
[0000000000fd8988] core interface debug: removing module "xcb_hotkeys"
[000000000102ddf8] core interface debug: removing module "hotkeys"
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: destroying
[0000000000f36a38] core playlist debug: deactivating the playlist
[0000000000fbe048] core audio output debug: removing module "alsa"
[0000000000fdf6e8] core playlist export debug: saving Media Library to file /home/stud/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf.tmp14649
[0000000000fdf6e8] core playlist export debug: looking for playlist export module matching "export-xspf": 4 candidates
[0000000000fdf6e8] core playlist export debug: using playlist export module "export"
[0000000000fdf6e8] core playlist export debug: removing module "export"
stud@milbvm:~/Big_One/LB-KA_01$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the libdvbpsi. [download](http://download.videolan.org/pub/libdvbpsi/)

I installed it and recompiled vlc with --enable-dvbpsi